# Absolute File Path

Tags: php, file, path, absolute

This problem is still not solved

A video PHP tutorial I am following is building a file called initialize.php in which it is using the PHP pre-defined constant Directory_Separator and then defining a site_root.  The site_root is the *absolute file path (not the webserver path)  for PHP to locate the files it needs*. He gave us the following code

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null :
    define ('SITE_ROOT', DS.'Users'.DS.'kevin'.DS.'Sites'.DS.'photo_gallery');
```

I am assuming the file path on his computer is root/users/kevin/sites/photogallery

I am not building the site on my computer, but rather directly online. I don't know what file path to insert instead.

As he emphasized that it's not the webserver path, but rather the file system path, what do I put instead. Just the domain name like this.

```
define('SITE_ROOT', DS. 'www.example.com');
```

He doesn't want the webserver path but the files are located online? so I don't get it.

**UPDATE**

The video tutorial used the following code

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null :
define ('SITE_ROOT', DS.'Users'.DS.'kevin'.DS.'Sites'.DS.'photo_gallery');
defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH',SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');
```

I used this code:

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT')? null: define('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH',SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');
```

I got this error message

> require_once(/hsphere/local/home/c263430/quoralist.com/includes/includes/config.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /hsphere/local/home/c263430/quoralist.com/includes/initialize.php
>   on line 11 Fatal error:
>   require_once(): Failed opening
>   required
>   '/hsphere/local/home/c263430/quoralist.com/includes/includes/config.php'
>   (include_path='.:/hsphere/shared/apache/libexec/php5ext/php/')
>   in
>   /hsphere/local/home/c263430/quoralist.com/includes/initialize.php
>   on line 11

UPDATE
using the 3 edits below by experimentX, as well as the following

```
define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'hsphere'.DS.'local'.DS.'home'.DS.'c263430'.DS.'quoralist.com');
```

I always got the error message

> Warning:
>   require_once(LIB_PATH/config.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /hsphere/local/home/c263430/quoralist.com/includes/initialize.php
>   on line 11 Fatal error:
>   require_once(): Failed opening
>   required 'LIB_PATH/config.php'
>   (include_path='.:/hsphere/shared/apache/libexec/php5ext/php/')
>   in
>   /hsphere/local/home/c263430/quoralist.com/includes/initialize.php
>   on line 11

Also,

Comment: Micahel i have updated the answer

Comment: Micahel i have again updated the answer –

Comment: As an alternative to `defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`, you can use the next construct: `defined('DS') || define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR')`. That looks much more cleaner and means: if `DS` is defined, we are done. Otherwise, define `DS`. (`||` is the OR operator)

Comment: @experimentX I tried your updated code but it didn't work. any suggestions.

Comment: @Michael I found your error see updates at last

Comment: @experimentX  thanks, but it didn't work for me. I updated the post. As you will see, I also tried the file path suggested by the error message. Any more suggestions?

Comment: well come in chat on `php` or on my facebook http://www.facebook.com/santoshlinkha

Comment: @experimentX where is chat on PHP? I don't use Facebook.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php or http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

```
defined('SITE_ROOT')? null: define('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

echo SITE_ROOT;
```

Instead of `define('SITE_ROOT', 'www.domain.com')` you should `define('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))`.

`www.domain.com` is the base url (of your site) while `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` is the absolute file path of FILE where it is defined. Using this path, you can set up a ROOT FOLDER for you site.

For example: you cannnot do `unlink('www.example.com\img1.jpg')` to delete `img1`

You should do `unlink(SITE_ROOT.DS.'img1.jpg')`;

Similarly for `move_uploaded_file` or any other directory or file function. i.e. your files are being moved and deleted by server computer(as php script is executed in server), so absolute file path is required.

Using this absolute path, you can navigate to the folder and access files on server.

[UPDATE]

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : 
    define ('SITE_ROOT', DS.'Users'.DS.'kevin'.DS.'Sites'.DS.'photo_gallery');
```

Though I don't own mac, the `web-root` is `Users/kevin/Sites/` on Mac and the `Users/kevin/Sites/photogallery` is the site root.

The tutor knows this so he is doing this. But we might not know this when our project is uploaded in webserver, so

```
defined('SITE_ROOT')? null: define('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Would be the most appropriate.

And as to `DS`, it is just a CONSTANT (`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`), which is defined because `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` would be too long to write. i.e.

```
  SITE_ROOT'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Users'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'kevin'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Sites'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'photo_gallery'
```

So, define it before you define SITE ROOT

```
defined('DS')? null: define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
defined('SITE_ROOT')? null: define('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

As the tutorial is done on MAC `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is `/`. And the sample is done on `localhost`, the tutor knows the absolute file path of his webserver so he is doing

**[ERROR: UPDATE]**

You got this error because defining this on `includes/initialize.php` assumes that your your `SITE_ROOT` is `yourwebroot/yourproject/includes` where it must have been `yourwebroot/yourproject/includes`.

There are two ways, one way is

to put `initialize.php` in `yourwebroot/yourproject`

And the other way is

```
defined('SITE_ROOT')? null: define('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DS."..".DS);
```

OR

```
defined('SITE_ROOT')? null: define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'..'.DS.realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

(I am not sure  but one of them should work)

Also try this

```
defined('SITE_ROOT')? null: define('SITE_ROOT', '/../'.realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Comment: thank you very much. I'm a newbie. could you explain a little more. Do I have to substitue in my actual domain name to your example? such as SITE_ROOT = www.example.com(dirname(__FILE__))?  or how would I do it. much appreciated if you can help more. Please edit your answer to show me exactly where the domain goes.

Comment: @Michal here it goes ... after 5 min

Comment: so I don't ever have to use my actual domain name www.example.com? are those words "realpath" "dirname" etc PHP terms that somehow pickup my domain name?

Comment: am I supposed to change realpath or something else with my domain www.example.com?

Comment: @experimentX also how do I use the Directory Separator DS in yours?

Comment: thank you thank you for the clarification. But your solution doesn't use the DS.  Do I have to include DS somewhere?  defined('SITE_ROOT')? null: define('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

Comment: @Michael Oops! i think i understand your problem now! you followed Kevin K... video tutorial from lynda I also did the same and had the same problem. I will update the andwer again in few minutes and alert you again

Comment: @experimentX yes, thank you. I think it's important to use the DS because in a subsequent line of code, he uses it (and I will too), for example defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH',SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

Comment: @experimentX I used your exact code but it didn't work. any suggestions?

Comment: @Michael how did you use it? where .. could you update in your question and also could you please add the error

Answer (score 1):

sorry, i have the answer for IMAGES not displaying

in photograph.php, just remove DS

```
public function image_path() {
  return $this->upload_dir.$this->filename;
}
```

working line is:

```
defined('SITE_ROOT')? null: define('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DS."..".DS);
```

Thanks!